# Blocks created using multiblock module are not working

Tags: blocks

1. Installed multiblock module.
2. Create duplicated blocks (structure > block > instance > create .. ) and placed them in footer1 region.
3. Original blocks are in very-top1 region.

Duplicated blocks are menu links. When I click those links, nothing happens. They definitely worked before. I am not sure why they dont work now. I must done something wrong.

My site address:  http://godrupal.info/. If you scroll to the bottom you will see the all the links. Do you know why those duplicated links are not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your site out specifically the footer area as you've instructed. This is not the module's issue but a Bootstrap/theming issue. Notice in the screenshot:

[image]

The block-9 block is using the col-md-12 which spans the whole content area and covering everything under it that's why the links aren't clickable.

I tested and just changed col-md-12 into col-md-2 and now the links are clickable.

Please check your markup and CSS to confirm.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped. Now the links are working.

Comment: Awesome! You're very welcome! :)